# ListPlot - using the range of variable in axis

Tags: plotting

I am plotting a list using the following command:

```
ListPlot[Table[f[x], {x, 0.01, 1.5, 0.015}]]
```

In the plot, the x-axis ranges from 0 to 100, which is the total number of points. How can I change the x-axis scale as to show the range of the variable x instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the option [DataRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DataRange.html):

```
f = Sin;
ListPlot[Table[f[x], {x, 0.01, 1.5, 0.015}], DataRange -> {0.01, 1.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, as suggested in a comment by @tchronis,

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0.01, 1.5, 0.015}]]
```

Comment: `ListPlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0.01, 1.5, 0.015}]]` will work too. This can help you work with parametric function too like `ListPlot[Table[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0.01, 1.5, 0.015}]]`